# sprintf and snprintf fail to encapsulate double

Tags: c++, printf

sprintf and snprintf are both stripping the last two digits of my decimals. It is failing to encapsulate my double value.

code:

```
int main(void)
{
        char command[70];
        char sendbuy[12];
        double biggestMark2;
        biggestMark2 = 0.00550006;
        sprintf(sendbuy,"%lf",biggestMark2);
        //snprintf(command, sizeof command, "php oin.php 155  %s", sendbuy);
        sprintf(command, "php oin.php 155 %s",sendbuy);
        cout << command << endl;
        cout << biggestMark2 << endl;
}
```

output:

```
 # ./veryTemp.o
php oin.php 155 0.005500
0.00550006
```

expected output:

```
 # ./veryTemp.o
php oin.php 155 0.00550006
0.00550006
```

How do I get all of my digits into my command variable?

Comment: Give it a precision (default is 6). `%.20f`.

Comment: And there's no such thing as `%lf`

Comment: @FreddieChopin: Oh, but there is. It's just indistinguishable from `%f` for the `printf`-family (there's a crucial difference for the `scanf` one).

Comment: @Deduplicator now it comes out a lot worse  :(  ->  php oin.php 155 0.01

Comment: @Deduplicator - so there is `%lf` for `scanf()`, but there is no `%lf` for `printf()` - I don't see a contradiction in that, as `printf()` is not `scanf()`.

Comment: If you're using C++ you should probably be using C++, not the old C library. 10 characters is not really enough to contain an arbitrary float.

Comment: "Now it comes out a lot worse": well of course it does! `sendbuy` is only 12 characters long...

Comment: @tadman: There are distinct advantages in having a proper formatting function, instead of having to hard-code everything. C++ fails there, at least the standard-library.

Comment: The C++ number formatting functions for strings, while quirky, do work and don't suffer from rampant buffer overflow problems like this code does.

Comment: @TonyK changing it to 50 doesn't help. sendbuy should only be the decimal which is 10 characters plus offset.

Comment: @nerd007 A `char[10]` can only contain 9 characters because of the `NULL` terminator.

Comment: @tadman I change it to 50, gross overkill. same. but that's why I made it 12. should of been one to spare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the formatter, %.8f will give you a precision of 8. It's fixed, so adding extra precision gets padded with 0s.

Answer (score 1):

Default precision of printing floating point is 6, as stated in the standard:

> 7.21.6.1 p8:
>
> f,F
>
> A double argument representing a floating-point number is converted to
> decimal notation in the style [−]ddd.ddd, where the number of digits after
> the decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification. `If the precision is missing, it is taken as 6;` if the precision is zero and the # flag is
> not specified, no decimal-point character appears.
> If a decimal-point
> character appears, at least one digit appears before it. The value is rounded to
> the appropriate number of digits.

Comment: @nerd007 - note what TonyK said in his comment - to print 20 decimal points you need something longer than a 12 character buffer...

Comment: char command[170];
        char sendbuy[52];
->  oin.php 155  0.005500   same.  :(

Comment: @nerd007 - it is really working for us... http://ideone.com/JyDd3L What compiler are you using and on what system?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C++, use C++:

```
int main(void)
{
  double biggestMark2 = 0.00550006;

  cout << "php oin.php 155 " << setprecision(10) << biggestMark2 << endl;
}
```

What you're looking for here is the [`setprecision()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) call to adjust formatting of doubles.

No static buffers here, no buffer overflows. It doesn't get any easier than this.

Comment: using `printf()` you can also avoid buffer overflow, I see no advantage in that regard.

Comment: Mixing and matching `printf` and `cout` makes for a mess of code. Pick one and stick to it.